# how to omit @XmlRootElement from JSON output with Jersey?

Tags: json, rest, jaxb, jersey

I'm trying to produce JSON from a list of simple objects. It works, but my output is wrapped with the classname:

```
{"classname":[{"name":"John Doe","title":"manager"} .....]}
```

What I would like to have is

```
[{"name":"John Doe","title":"manager"} .....]
```

I understand this is because I have @XmlRootElement on my class, but if I omit that, then I get an error:

```
A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type
java.util.List<MyClass>, and MIME media type application/json was not found
```

I have set up the com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature as true, although I'm not 100% sure if it is in the right place. I'm using Embedded Jetty and I set the parameter for the ServletHolder

Comment: don't you have a name for the instance of your class? It sgould be there instead of `classname`

Comment: MyClass? it's the type of the List.

Comment: I gave up on embedded Jetty and tried "regular" Jetty with web.xml instead - works great. Still, if someone knows how to set this up with embedded Jetty, without the web.xml - please post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gson for creating a string of your array. that should give you the desired answer.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson([{"name":"John Doe","title":"manager"} .....]);
```

for more info: http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-java-to-json.jsp

javadoc: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html

Comment: This will help in converting java list into a string that can be parsed by Mime media: application/json

Comment: If you don't want to add any more dependencies to your project. try adding toString() after the array. I guess that will also work